# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to run this code for my analysis.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import xarray as xr

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

GPCC=xr.open_dataset("sellonlat_bil_remap_GPCC_precip_2000_2015.nc")
ccsm_clm=xr.open_dataset("sellonlat_bil_remap_addc_monmean_daymean_2m_tempe_warm_new_2000-2015.nc")

tempe=GPCC['precip'].sel(time=slice('2000-01-16','2015-12 16')).groupby('time.month').mean('time',skipna=False).mean('lon').mean('lat')

tempe1=ccsm_clm['APRC'].sel(time=slice('2000-01-16','2015-12 16')).groupby('time.month').mean('time',skipna=False).mean('lon').mean('lat')
```

It is working well for GPCC data but showing the following error with the ccsm_clm data:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'

I am looking for suggestions.

Comment: Can you confirm exactly where it fails? Is it `ccsm_clm['APRC'].sel(time=slice('2000-01-16','2015-12 16'))`? What are the types in `ccsm_clm`?

Comment: I think it not able to read the time from the ccsm_clm data. I have even converted it from 64-bit offset NetCDF to classic but it's still not working. This is what I got after ncdump-  dimensions:
       
variables:
        double time(time) ;
              float lon(lon)  
        float lat(lat) ;
                     float APRC(time, lat, lon) ;
                          APRC:_FillValue = -9.e+33f ;
                APRC:missing_value = -9.e+33f ;
                APRC:cell_methods = "time: sum" ;

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the exact expression in which it fails? Currently the last line contains a number of calls. It's difficult to parse the comment

Comment: I have edited the question. This error is what I am getting in the end.

Comment: Can you break up the final line into just one call? e.g. if you only run `ccsm_clm['APRC'].sel(time=slice('2000-01-16','2015-12 16'))`, does that still raise an error?

Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: It is still showing the same error after running the line you have suggested. In starting it is showing-                                     
TypeError: must be real number, not string   and then the same error in the post.

Comment: OK, what are the values on the time dimension? It sounds like `ccsm_clm['APRC'].time` are numbers, not dates

Comment: At first, the model dates are like, 2015-11-15 23:30:00, but I used CDO to change the time axis and made it similar to the observation, 2015-12-01 00:00:00. And the whole data looks like -                                                                                                                -1 :       Date     Time   Level Gridsize    Miss :     Minimum        Mean     Maximum 
     1 : 2000-01-01 00:00:00       0     4590       0 :    0.026947      54.087      579.59 
     2 : 2000-02-01 00:00:00       0     4590       0 :   0.0010522      38.200      433.08

Comment: What type are they?

Comment: I don't what exactly I need to tell but ncdump shows following-                            
             double time(time) ;
                time:standard_name = "time" ;
                time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
                time:units = "day as %Y%m%d.%f" ;
                time:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
                time:axis = "T" ;
        double time_bnds(time, bnds) ;                                                                       
       float APRC(time, lat, lon) ;
            
                APRC:cell_methods = "time: sum" ;

Comment: What does `ccsm_clm['APRC'].time.dtype` return?

Comment: The time format is not in datetime64[ns] format. I guess that is what producing this error.

Comment: It wasn't the most efficient process, but happy we've found the issue!

Comment: Yeah. Thank you so much